# Page footers across all Stack Exchange sites list MathOverflow under multiple categories

Tags: bug, status-completed

It's listed under "Technology", "Life/Arts", "Culture/Recreation", "Science" as well as "Others"!

I think we should be under Science, *after* mathematics.SE.

Comment: Duplicate: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/185722/mathoverflow-has-become-stackexchanges-main-attraction

Comment: Oops, I accidentally migrated this; I didn't realize it was so easy to do!

Comment: You can clear migration history.

Comment: Well, think about it... MO is a generic SE site now. Being generic it must intersect every dense set in the ground model, and in particular it now fits *all* the previously known categories! :-P

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's only in one column now.

Adjusting the position will take more effort; please post that as a separate [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request).

Comment: It's not a big deal, so let's for now drop the request about ordering.

Comment: I’m not sure whether it’s related, but http://stackexchange.com/sites?view=list#traffic lists MO as the last, with “5 visits/day”. That must be off by several orders of magnitude.

Comment: Could it be that the number of visits is recorded only since migration, but it’s being divided by the total age of the site?